# Write unit test for metadata

Tags: javascript

Can someone give an example how to write unit test for this function by using async and await....

```
function writeFragment(fragment) {
  return metadata.put(fragment.ownerId, fragment.id, fragment);
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: you can't write a test for this without mocking the metadata object. If you receive it as a parameter then it's easier to unit test.

Comment: I am using Jest